# PHP7/PDO: Returning PDOStatement Object and fetch data later

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently in the process of updating my web application from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7, therefore I need to alter the database abstraction class that has been using the old MySQL-Extension.
The class has a method "Query()" where SQL statements are being prepared and executed and a method "Fetch()" which fetches a single row and returns it. See the simplified versions:

```
function Query($query='')
{
    $result = $this->connection->Prepare($query);
    $result->Execute();
    return $result;
}

function Fetch($resource=null)
{
    return $resource->Fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

So basically what I am trying to do is this:

```
$statement = Query('SELECT * FROM Test');
$firstRow = Fetch($statement);
```

print_r($statement) shows me this:

```
PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => SELECT * FROM Test
)
```

But when I call "Fetch", there is no row returned. Can someone tell if it's possible to return PDOStatement objects and pass them into other functions/methods for "later use"?

PS: Of course I know that this is not best practice but I am trying to avoid having to alter thousands of lines of code in the application.

Comment: Simplified version seems correct. Do a debug. What is the value of `$statement`?

Comment: I edited this question and added the value of $statement. So you're saying that this is technically possible?

Comment: Shouldn't `function Query` be a `public static function` if you're calling `Query()`

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Now what is the value of `$firstRow`?

Comment: And make sure that your statement executed correctly. Result of `$result->Execute();` __must__ be true.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help so far! $firstRow is "false"... Yes the statement is being executed correctly and returns "true".

Comment: Hi again, I just found out "false" was returned earlier in the code when i debugged it. I can confirm that passing PDOStatements works! Thanks again.